# Primality test for n by checking whether n divides 2^n-2

Tags: java

So the question I have is how do i implement this formula: A positive integer n (larger than 1) is a prime if and only if n divides 2^n-2. So far i came up with this code, but i am stuck. I am a newbie at this, just starting to learn java, any help would be great, thanks!

```
public boolean isPrime(int x){
     if(x==1) 
        return false; 
     if(x==2) 
        return true;
     if(x % 2 == 0)
        return false;

     for(int i=3; i<Math.sqrt(x); i++)
```

This is where i am confused.

Comment: Your formula doesn't make sense for a primality test (at least the way it's worded here). What part are you confused about?

Comment: So you are trying to write a method that returns whether the parameter is a prime?

Comment: The primality test is correct, actually. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113879/prove-that-if-2n-1-is-prime-then-n-divides-2n-2

Comment: Why did you put some only marginally related code into your question?

Comment: Isn't enough `return ((int)Math.pow(2, x-2)) % x)==0`?

Comment: @BrunoZamengo sure, for `x` up to 32.. that's not really useful is it E: actually, doesn't OP mean (2^n)-2 in the first place

Comment: That is all i have so far @Henry, that is why i was seeking help.

Comment: @harold, it's approx 53 (= # of mantissa bits in a double-precision value)

Comment: @JasonS it doesn't matter what a double can hold, it's an `int`

Comment: oh -- duh, I missed that point. Right. Get rid of the cast and it should work up to about 53...

Comment: @JasonS Your link says that `2^n - 1` is prime, not `n` itself which this question is stating (correctly or incorrectly I don't know).

Comment: @DenisJones -- suggest you edit the title to say "Primality test for n by checking whether n divides 2^n-2"

Comment: @Gendarme: read the contents. [Fermat's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) says a^n is congruent to a (mod n) if n prime.

Comment: Although the converse is *not* true, so I guess I have to amend my earlier statement and say that it's not sufficient as a primality test. [Carmichael numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) like 561 = 51 * 11 pass this test: 561 divides (2^561 - 2).

Comment: So just returning this would work "((int)Math.pow(2, x-2)) % x)==0" ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct way, calculating 2<sup>n</sup>-2 and then testing for divisibility, is obviously completely unscalable. Fortunately we can just work modulo `n` the entire way, that way there will be no big numbers. This proof of concept uses `BigInteger` anyway, just because it has a convenient implementation of `modPow`, it could be rewritten without that.

```
static boolean isProbablyPrime(int n) {
    BigInteger bigN = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
    BigInteger t = two.modPow(bigN, bigN);
    return t.longValue() == 2;
}
```

I renamed the function because it passes some non-primes, such as 561 as mentioned in the comments.

Try it on [ideone](https://ideone.com/nJCF6W).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help! I will have to read up on the BigInteger library. So, this method wouldn't be the most sufficient to find primes since it does show us some non-primes. @harold

Comment: @DenisJones it does find primes, but it also "finds" a bunch of numbers that aren't primes. There are some deterministic [fast tests for narrow integers](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1326/020-Forisek.pdf) if that's what you're interested in.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again. @harold